# Replicate Specific Tables with fully qualified statements removed

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master, master-slave-replication

Currently we have a replication system that is a master to slave, which that slave is also a master. We are replicating our web server to our stats server so we can report on users traffic as well. We've discovered recently though that our, `replicate-rewrite-db` rule doesn't correct `fully qualified statements` (e.g. databases included in the query). So we have

```
replicate-rewrite-db=web_live->stats
```

in our my.cnf but our phpmyadmin on `update`s/`insert`s generates queries like:

```
UPDATE  
    `web_live`.`users` 
SET
    `useremail` =  'chris@example.com' 
WHERE 
    `users`.`userid` = 85;
```

where as it should be:

```
UPDATE  
    `users` 
SET  
    `useremail` =  'chris@example.com' 
WHERE 
    `users`.`userid` = 85;
```

or, as we expected:

```
UPDATE  
    `stats`.`users` 
SET  
    `useremail` =  'chris@example.com' 
WHERE 
    `users`.`userid` = 85;
```

because we expected the `replicate-rewrite-db` to rewrite all calls to the older DB name, however that directive only applies to `use` cases.

Is there a way to either

1. just have the table names be called in queries or
2. safely and reliable remove the DB name?

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, file a bug at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: @RickJames I'm not sure it is a bug, from the documentation it seemed like this was the designed affect, `Tells the slave to create a replication filter that translates the default database (that is, the one selected by USE) to to_name if it was from_name on the master.` I'm hoping I'm just missing something here and some DBA will know a way around this issue I've found. With just 14 views I'm thinking of moving it to SO to just get more attention though.